# C++ modulo iterator in loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator

Is there a way where I can write this `for` loop

```
vector<int> vec{1,2,3,4,5,6};
for (int i=0; i<vec.size(); ++i)
    float result = vec[i]-vec[(i+1)%vec.size()];//Subtract vec[0] from vec[5] in last iteration.
```

in a version with iterators? Thus, something like this:

```
vector<int> vec{1,2,3,4,5,6};
for (vector<int>::iterator it=vec.begin(); it!=vec.end(); ++it)
    float result = *it - *((it+1)%vec.size());
```

Comment: `it + 1 == vec.end() ? vec.begin() : it + 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the ternary `?:` operator and either select `begin` or `it + 1` depending on whether the current `it` iterator is pointing to the element previous to the end or not:

```
for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it) {
    float result = *it - *((it + 1 == vec.end()) ? vec.begin() : it + 1);
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a74951097953f34)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think if I were to do it that way, I think I would write

```
for (auto i1 = vec.end() - 1, i2 = vec.begin(); i2 != vec.end(); i1 = i2++) {
    result = *i1 - *i2;
}
```